# Listings doesn't recognize Pascal // comment

Tags: listings, comments

listings doesn't seem to recognize the Pascal comment syntax '//' ({...} works fine). The text isn't formatted correctly.

A minimum example to reproduce:

```
\lstdefinestyle{pascalstyle}{
    language=Pascal, 
    commentstyle=\color{red}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
       { this comment is correctly formatted}
       // that one isn't 
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Is there any oppurtunity to learn `//`to listings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `morecomment`.

```
\documentclass{Article}
\usepackage{listings,color}
\lstdefinestyle{pascalstyle}{
    language=Pascal,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    sensitive=false,
    %morecomment=[l][\color{red}]{//},
    morecomment=[l]{//},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=pascalstyle]
       { this comment is correctly formatted}
       // that one isn't
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]